# Any way of knowing when a listview has scrolled to top?

Tags: android, listview, header

I'm trying to add a stikcy header to a listview. I've put the header-field and the listview inside a relativelayout and defined the listview's android:layout_below="@id/header".

The problem is that I want the listview and the header to be positioned at the same place when the listview is not scrolled to the top. The header's background is transparent. I drew an amazing image in paint to illustrate how I want them to interact.

[image: Header and ListView]

I figured I could override the listviews onscrollistener and change the listviews layout_below-tingy at runtime when it's getScrollY() == 0, but that seems to happen all the time.

Has anyone done something similar that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to call getFirstVisiblePosition

Comment: Thanks, now I  just need to figure out how I can make the header ease in over the listview.